# Creating a Macro in Excel which executes the other Macro every 2 seconds

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro called `UpdateMacro` which updates my Database from my Excel

I want to create a macro called `RepeatMacro` where it executes the `UpdateMacro` every 2 seconds automatically and only Start and Stop Buttons are to be provided to start and Stop execution of the `RepeatMacro`.

How can it be done?

Comment: Have you considered updating when necessary rather than blindly updating every 2 seconds? [This](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx) might help with what you're currently asking, though...

Comment: @jswolf19 : No it is a neccesity of my application to update once every 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google for `Application.OnTime`

E.g.

```
Dim dtNextRunTime As Date
dtNextRunTime = Now + TimeSerial(0,0,2)
Application.OnTime dtNextRunTime, "MyProcedure", True
```

To clear a previously set procedure, you need to save the time at which it was scheduled )e.g. dtNextRunTime above), then use:

```
Application.OnTime dtNextRunTime, "MyProcedure", False
```

Here's a sample VB module with methods StartSchedule / StopSchedule to get you going:

```
Private m_dtScheduledTime As Date
Private m_lDelaySeconds As Long
Private m_bIsScheduled As Boolean

Private Sub DoWork()

    m_bIsScheduled = False

    ' ... do your work

    ' Reschedule at the same frequency once completed
    StartSchedule m_lDelaySeconds, "DoWork"

End Sub

Public Sub StartSchedule(ByVal DelaySeconds As Long)
    StopSchedule
    m_lDelaySeconds = DelaySeconds
    m_dtScheduledTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, m_lDelaySeconds)
    Application.OnTime m_dtScheduledTime, "DoWork", True
    m_bIsScheduled = True
End Sub

Public Sub StopSchedule()
    If m_bIsScheduled Then
        Application.OnTime m_dtScheduledTime, "DoWork", False
        m_bIsScheduled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.I checked `Application.OnTime` and got an impression that it is for running a macro at a specified time. But I dont need to just run the macro at one specified time. I want to run it for every seconds throughout 24 hours. So I cannot just specify the time. What can be the other options?

Comment: @PARTH, Well, at the end of the macro, you have it set a new timer for 2 seconds later...

Comment: @jswolf19: Thanks Joe. And yes not to forget contribution of @jswolf19 in making this answer Worth. Thanks JsWolf19, your link helped a lot. :) :) Thanks to both of you guys. It worked..!!

Answer (score 0):

This will run `UpdateMacro` every two seconds, assuming UpdateMacro takes less than two seconds to run.

```
Sub RepeatMacro()
    Dim lastRunTime
    Do
        lastRunTime = Now
        Range("A1") = "Last run: " & Format(lastRunTime, "hh:nn:ss")
        Call UpdateMacro
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait lastRunTime + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    Loop
End Sub

Sub UpdateMacro()
    Debug.Print "running UpdateMacro"
End Sub
```

**EDIT** To start and stop `RepeatMacro` from your sheet, make a start button and a stop button, and put the following code in your Sheet module. Also notice that I added a `DoEvents` in `RepeatMacro` above.

```
Private Sub StartButton_Click()
    Call RepeatMacro
End Sub

Private Sub StopButton_Click()
    MsgBox "Stopped."
    End
End Sub
```

Now just saying `End` is poor practice, but you get the idea.

Comment: @Jean-Francois Corbett: Thanks for the reply. How to Stop this RepeatMacro?

Comment: @PARTH: Edited my answer to address this.

Comment: Yeah I read it. Thanks :) I will try out the code soon and get back to you

Comment: Application.OnTime is soooo much better than this.

Comment: Soooo much so that it's worth a downvote even though it works?! Now you little idealist, you.

Comment: @Jean-FRancois Corbett : Thanks for the help..!! But I got an answer from Joe. +1 for your effort. Also one small correction in your answer is `Format(lastRunTime, "hh:mm:ss")` in place of `hh:nn:ss`. Thanks once again..!! Carry on the Good work :)

Comment: `hh:nn:ss` is not a mistake. `n` is supported as a format identifier for minutes, to help avoid confusion with `m` for months. At least in Excel 2003, it is... I did test the code before posting it.